# How to set state in a function which is in a second JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in `app.js` which is calling a function in a second JavaScript file `client.js`, i wish to set the state of `showError` to true when the createTimer function fails and `checkStatus` throws an error. This way I am able to show the `ErrorSegment` when the function has failed.

The error I'm getting is: `client.js:93 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

How can i show the error segment when the createTimer function fails?

Bonus question, how can I revert the state efficiently to false after let's say 5 seconds or whenever i perform another action.

app.js:

```
const TimersDashboard = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            timers: [] ,
            showError: false,
        };
    },
    createTimer: function (timer) {
        client.createTimer(t);
    },
    render: function () {
         return (
             <ErrorSegment
                 showError={this.state.showError}
             />
         );
    },
});
```

client.js:

```
window.client = (function () {
  function createTimer(data) {
    return fetch('/api/timers', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then(checkStatus)
     .catch(onError);
  }

  function onError() {
    this.setState({ showError: true; });
  }

  return {
    createTimer,
  };
}());
```

Comment: How you import js files in html document?

Comment: `<script type="text/babel" src="./client.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/babel" src="./app.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `onError` as the part of `TimersDashboard` component and not `client.js`, and pass it into the `createTimer` function in addition to `data`:

```
    function createTimer(data, onError) { // onError is no longer a part of client.js 
                                          // it comes from TimersDashboard
```

Comment: onError (now in app.js) doesn't seem to get called when there is an error thrown in client.js. The code for createTimer in client.js is unchanged except: `function createTimer(data, onError) {..`

Comment: have you also changed `client.createTimer(t);` to `client.createTimer(t,this.onError);` ?

Comment: It works, however a lot of other stuff stopped working, but I can figure that out myself. Thanks a lot. Are you able to give a little explanation about what is going on when sending the onError function into createTimer and what happens when the error is caught?

Comment: [Every function in JavaScript is an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), and now you've made your `createTimer` a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). When the error is caught, the `onError` function that you've passed into `createTimer` gets called and the rejection reason is passed into it as the first argument, which means that you can inspect the error in your `onError(reason)` function and provide a more detailed information to a user (in case when having a simple flag is not sufficient).